# build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0 include Wearable app

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, gradle-experimental

I have a working app in Android Studio using classpath **'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0' and gradle 2.8.**

As mentioned in google docs, to include your wearable app with your APK, you need to declare the wear app into the phone app gradle file as dependency something like this:

```
dependencies {   
//other dependencies

//wearApp project(':Wear')
wearApp project(path: ':Wear', configuration: 'google')
}
```

But I get an error on the line where I include my wear app with the error message:

```
Gradle sync failed: Gradle DSL method not found: 'wearApp()'
```

This is because the experimental gradle plugin is not recognizing this command ( this is for standard gradle)...

The question is, What is the command for including Wear app with gradle-experimental:0.4.0 plugin ???

** update

Added this to gradle also:

```
android.buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable = true
        embedMicroApp = true  // this should enable the WEAR command, idk...
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `google` a `productFlavor` in your build.gradle?

Comment: Yes. I have checked this. Wear is the name of the module/app that is for wearable devices and build flavor is google.

Comment: I have even added in my gradle * pleace chekc the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe that when you have `productFlavors` defined in your build.gradle, you need to reference them in your `dependencies` section, like such:

```
dependencies {
    // other dependencies
    googleWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'google')
}
```

At least, this is what I'm doing in a similar situation. Give it a try and see if it works!

Comment: Are you getting the same error? Have you narrowed the problem down to build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0?